# Closed form expression for $x$

Tags: closed-form, inverse-function

We define the following relation:

$$y = \frac{(1+x)^n - 1}{x}$$

Alternatively,

$$y = \sum_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} x^{k-1}$$

Where $n$ is an integer and $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers. How can we find a closed form expression for $x$ in terms of $y$ and $n$?

Comment: The equation in $x$ is a polynomial fo degree $n-1$. Is $n\leq 5$, you could have solutions with radicals. Otherwise, no closed form. If you consider the problem for small $x$, approximations could be made.

Comment: We can also in principle express $x$ as an infinite series (or more general, a limit of any other appropriate recursion), which would depend on $y$ and $n$.

Comment: With $x=t-1,t^n-ty=1-y$. This requires a [general trinomial series solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial)